How to draw a horizontal line in Oracle Apex Bar Graph
Given a certain user input say, 20. I want to draw a horizontal line across the bar graph (which is already created) at y=20 using oracle apex.
I have tried adding another 'series' to the bar graph but I was not quite sure how to carry that out. I have also seen some solutions try to use custom XML but once again I was not sure how to execute this. Any help is appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What's the point of your comment, @Brentspine? Kunal provided enough information to identify both the problem and its solution. Do you use Apex at all? If not, perhaps you shouldn't comment questions related to it.

This example is based on Scott's sample EMP table. It displays employees who work in department 30 and their salaries. Additionally, graph displays horizontal line at value of 1000.

region type is Chart; go ti its Attributes pane and set chart type to combination (because we'll be combining bar and line charts)

region source is a simple query:
select ename, 
       sal, 
       1000 hor_line               --> here's your horizontal line value
from emp
where deptno = 30


create two series:

the 1st one is named "salary"; its type = Bar; label = ENAME, value = SAL
the 2nd one is named "hor_line"; its type = Line; label = ENAME, value = HOR_LINE



Run the page; result is

